# Implementation of JavaScript Class that works with Closure Compiler

Tags: javascript, oop, class, google-closure-compiler

Is there any implementation of class-like inheritance for JavaScript that works with Closure Compiler's `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS`?

It looks like [John Resig's implementation](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the simplest and a pretty common approachs to set up inheritence:

```
function Parent() {}

function Child() {}

Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
```

and it works fine with the closure compiler. I'm not sure if `Object.create` is properly recognized, but have a look at the implementation of [`goog.inherits`](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/closure_goog_base.js.html) from the closure library, which basically does the same.

Comment: The compiler currently only recognizes "goog.inherits" and direct assignments to prototypes:

Comment: I've noticed that closure compiler chokes on setting the prototype via Object.create -- all your super constructor calls will start failing.  My workaround was to set: Child['prototype'] = Object.create(...) to allow the super constructors to parse normally again

Answer (score 0):

The compiler currently only recognizes "goog.inherits" and direct assignments to prototypes:

```
Child.prototype = new Parent();
```

The Object.create metaphor is an obvious addition but hasn't been done yet.  To get anything else recognized requires either the definition of a new coding convention class (which is how goog.inherits is recognized during type checking) or a change to the compiler (as might be required for Object.create).

If want support for Object.create, you will want to file an issue here:

https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/issues/list